# Adding a Style to Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps

I have variable style written in java-script, but I don't know where to place it so that it start working.

I've tried placing it inside the function initmap () { .. but it's not working. 
https://jsfiddle.net/hute2o63/8/ 
Here's my style:

```
var featureOpts = [ { "featureType": "landscape", "stylers": [ { "hue": "#FFA800" }, { "saturation": 0 }, { "lightness": 0 }, { "gamma": 1 } ] }, { "featureType": "road.highway", "stylers": [ { "hue": "#53FF00" }, { "saturation": 0 }, { "lightness": -1.4210854715202004e-14 }, { "gamma": 1 } ] }, { "featureType": "road.arterial", "stylers": [ { "hue": "#FBFF00" }, { "saturation": 0 }, { "lightness": 0 }, { "gamma": 1 } ] }, { "featureType": "road.local", "stylers": [ { "hue": "#00FFFD" }, { "saturation": 0 }, { "lightness": 0 }, { "gamma": 1 } ] }, { "featureType": "water", "stylers": [ { "hue": "#0078FF" }, { "saturation": 0 }, { "lightness": 0 }, { "gamma": 1 } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "stylers": [ { "hue": "#9FFF00" }, { "saturation": 0 }, { "lightness": 0 }, { "gamma": 1 } ] } ];
```

Any help?

Comment: Try this page, it might help - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Comment: Looking to your jsfiddle, you are not providing a valid API-KEY here: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KE‌​Y&callback=initMap" async defer>`. You need to generate one on the goggle developer site if not already done.